# Simple SQL update query taking 50 minute to execute in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update, sql-server-2014-express

My simple SQL update query with joins is taking 50 minutes to execute and I'm not sure why. Sometimes the same query will execute in less than a minute but some time it takes a long time.

Below is the update query:

```
UPDATE [Analytics] 
SET [INumber] = S.[INo],   
    [Date] = S.[date],
    [State] = S.[State],
    [State] = S.[State],
    [To Code] = S.[to code]
FROM [Analytics] A
INNER JOIN [Report] S ON RTRIM(LTRIM(A.[Order ID])) = RTRIM(LTRIM(S.[CNumber]))
                      AND S.UniqueID = @UniqueID
WHERE A.[Status] = 'Valid' 
  AND A.UniqueID = @UniqueID
```

Somebody help me to identify the root cause as sometimes its executing fast and sometimes it takes long time.

In the above query: `Analytics` table contains 1,700,000 records and `Report` table contains some 150,000 records.

Comment: Could there be any other processes which are locking the table, which might explain why it takes longer in certain cases?

Comment: Please use **internationally standardized** measurement values - thousands, millions, billions ....

Comment: have you tried turning on the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option and looking at that? if possible, do that, screenshot it and attach.

Comment: Try with this, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33770

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, No other procesess locking the table, this is the only query is executing on the table and i could see some times it will run in seconds and someother times it takes longer time

Comment: @RodneyEllis, i am not able to attache execution plan image here